# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.configure(StandardJMeterEngine.java:176)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, jmeter

I'm trying to run Jmeter test plan via java and below is the code,

```
package com.jmeter;
import org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine;
import org.apache.jmeter.save.SaveService;
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import org.apache.jorphan.collections.HashTree;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
public class JMeterFromExistingJMX {
    public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        // JMeter Engine
        StandardJMeterEngine jmeter = new StandardJMeterEngine();
        // Initialize Properties, logging, locale, etc.

        JMeterUtils.loadJMeterProperties("c:\\JMeter\\apache-jmeter-3.0\\bin\\jmeter.properties");
        JMeterUtils.setJMeterHome("c:\\JMeter\\apache-jmeter-3.0");
        JMeterUtils.initLogging();// you can comment this line out to see extra log messages of i.e. DEBUG level
        JMeterUtils.initLocale();
        // Initialize JMeter SaveService
        SaveService.loadProperties();
        // Load existing .jmx Test Plan
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("c:\\JMeter\\apache-jmeter-3.0\\extras\\Test.jmx");
        HashTree testPlanTree = SaveService.loadTree(in);
        in.close();
        // Run JMeter Test
        jmeter.configure(testPlanTree);
        jmeter.run();
    }
}
```

and below are .jars files I've added in my classpath,
[Classpath Libraries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0lpc.png)

> While Compiling the aforementioned code, I'm getting below exception,

INFO    2017-01-28 20:25:58.549 [jmeter.e] (): Listeners will be started after enabling running version
INFO    2017-01-28 20:25:58.572 [jmeter.e] (): To revert to the earlier behaviour, define jmeterengine.startlistenerslater=false

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jmeter.engine.StandardJMeterEngine.configure(StandardJMeterEngine.java:176)
    at com.jmeter.JMeterFromExistingJMX.main(JMeterFromExistingJMX.java:32)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 0):

1. Upgrade to the [latest JMeter version](http://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) (3.1 as of now), JMeter 2.6 is 5+ years old
2. According to the [Five Ways To Launch a JMeter Test without Using the JMeter GUI](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/5-ways-launch-jmeter-test-without-using-jmeter-gui) article

   > To execute an existing JMeter test from Java code or to create one through programming, basic Java knowledge is a must, and the following are mandatory:
   >
   > 1. Have JMeter installed somewhere
   > 2. Have the required JMeter jars from **/lib** and especially **/lib/ext** folders of your JMeter installation in your project or module class path.

   so you need to remove apachejmeter_core-2.6.jar and add the libraries from the latest JMeter version installation folder instead.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. But even after doing the aforementioned as well, getting the same error